# When `let y = x`, is it possible for `y !== x`

Tags: javascript

Is there **any** case where

```
let x = y;
console.log(y !== x) //=> true
```

So far, no case has worked, neither object nor symbol

?

Comment: Here is a very short one: `let y = NaN; let x = y; console.log(y !== x);`. Searches will yield a ton of similar questions, maybe not this exact one (probably also exactly this, but not sure). They usually give a pretty good overview of the common pitfalls for "is this possible".

Comment: Check out this [sameness comparisons table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#A_model_for_understanding_equality_comparisons) on MDN. There are quite a few cases.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just found out.

Using getters and setters.

If `y` is a global getter and returns a different value each time, this is possible.

```js
// Defining y.
((i) => {
  Object.defineProperty(this, "y", {
    get: () => i++
  })
})(0)
// y is going to be one more than the previous value it gave,
// but is starts with 1.

// The magical testing...
let x = y;
console.log(x === y); // It returns `false`!
// Even y is not y.
console.log(y === y);
```